# Ruby classes: initialize self vs. @variable

Tags: ruby

Can someone explain the difference between initializing "self" and having @variables when defining classes?

Here's an example

```
class Child < Parent
  def initialize(self, stuff):
    self.stuff = stuff
    super()
  end
end
```

So in this case, wouldn't I be able to replace `self.stuff` with `@stuff`? What's the difference? Also, the `super()` just means whatever is in the Parent initialize method the Child should just inherit it right?

Comment: Down below you'll find excellent answers for the first part of your question. When `super()` is evaluated, the initialize method of the parent class is called without any arguments. This is one of the rare cases in ruby where you cannot omit the parentheses for a simple method call. If you do nevertheless, the initialize method of the superclass is called **with the arguments** you passed into the initialize method of the `Child` class.

Comment: It looks like you are getting confused between Ruby and Python (are you trying to learn both at the same time?)  In Ruby, you don't put a `:` after the method argument list, and `initialize` doesn't get a reference to `self`.  In Python, `self` is explicitly passed into the constructor (or whatever it's called in Python), and your `initialize` method looks very similar to how it would look in Python.  In Ruby, you can always refer to `self` without having to explicitly pass it in to methods.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

In general, no, `self.stuff = stuff` and `@stuff = stuff` are different. The former makes a method call to `stuff=` on the object, whereas the latter directly sets an instance variable. The former invokes a method which may be public (unless specifically declared private in the class), whereas the latter is always setting a private instance variable.

Usually, they look the same because it is common to define `attr_accessor :stuff` on classes. `attr_accessor` is roughly equivalent to the following:

```
def stuff
  @stuff
end

def stuff=(s)
  @stuff = s
end
```

So in that case, they are functionally identical. However, it is possible to define the public interface to allow for different results and side-effects, which would make those two "assignments" clearly different:

```
def stuff
  @stuff_called += 1    # Keeps track of how often this is called, a side effect
  return @stuff
end

def stuff=(s)
  if s.nil?             # Validation, or other side effect. This is not triggered when setting the instance variable directly
    raise "Argument should not be nil"
  end
  @stuff = s
end
```

Answer (score 6):

You actually can't use `self.stuff=` unless you specifically create an `attr_writer` for modifying that value.

In fact, these are equivalent:

```
class Child
  attr_writer :stuff
end

class Child
  def stuff=(val)
    @stuff = val
  end
end
```

It is more common to use an `attr_writer` if that is the functionality you want, rather than the explicit method. But you will often use an explicit method if you want to perform extra error checking or change the way the assignment works.

To your question of when to use `@stuff =` and when to use `self.stuff =`, I would use the former if you only have simple assignments and if your class is simple, and would move towards the latter if your requirements might become more complicated. There are many other reasons too, but it's more a matter of style than anything else.

Comment: I believe those are actually **not** equivalent.  The first defines an *instance method* `stuff=`.  The second defines a *class method* of `Child` called `stuff=`.

Comment: @ChrisRice: indeed, I fixed that.