# How to use cattr_accessor to define config in a Rails initializer

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Given the following class (this is the actual class there is no other code)

```
class PageRepo
  cattr_accessor :root_path
end
```

and initializer file

```
PageRepo.root_path = Rails.root.join("content")
```

When I run 
`rails console`

```
PageRepo.root_path 
=> PageRepo.root_path
=> #<Pathname:/Users/blah/my_rails_app/content/pages>
```

However when I try to access this in my rails controller the root_path value is **nil**. (I've inspected this with web_console.)

No other class subclasses or is a parent of the PageRepo class and I'm not setting the root_path to nil anywhere at class level or instance level after the initializer stage. I have restarted spring and my server multiple times to no avail.

Is there something I'm not aware of when it comes to either Rails initializers or cattr_accessor?

**Update**

I'd like to set the path like this because throughout my code I will be initialising a PageRepo instance and the path will not change. However, it may change across different environments. I.e. in development it the path will be different than that of the test and production environments. Whilst I could just do

`def initialize
  @root_path = ENV['ROOT_PATH']
end`

I'd prefer to not force the programmer to use ENV VARS to do this and hence my attempt above.

Answer (score 0):

My solution would be just using a `class` method

```
class PageRepo
  self.root_path
     Rails.root.join("content")
  end 
end
```

`PageRepo.root_path` would return `#<Pathname:/Users/blah/my_rails_app/content/pages>`.

You want to have `#<Pathname:/Users/blah/my_rails_app/content/pages>`? or this depends on the action?

I believe your initializer is not working

an interesting [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12097726/ruby-classes-initialize-self-vs-variable#12097864), what you are trying to achieve is writing something like this in the `class initializer` or `constructor`

```
class PageRepo
  self.initialize
     self.root_path = Rails.root.join("content")
  end 
end
```

but I never saw `self.initialize` being used with rails. so I believe the first approach is better.

Comment: Thanks Fabrizio for your response. Unfortunately I don't want to hard code the path. I've updated my question to explain why and what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: @robodisco do you have any idea why your solution is not working? is the initializer code executing at server start? you can check by setting in the initializer a breakpoint bindingpry. 
When does that value change? Once the classe get instanciated? or once the Class code is required?